# What happens when a string with only whitespaces is trimmed?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList and a string which is comprised of only spaces:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
String data="               ";
a.add(data.trim())
```

`a.isEmpty()` returns false.

How do I check that a has no elements like data?

Comment: isEmpty will return false because you’ve added a String still, albeit with no spaces.

Comment: You called add() on a, and you did not remove anything out of it afterwards. So it is not empty, it is guaranteed to contain at least one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I do to check that a has no elements?

```
if (myList.isEmpty()){...}
```

will do that.   So what you actually do.
But what you want is checking that a list has no empty elements. Which is a different thing.
No `List` subclasses provide such as behavior as it is a functional specificity.
To solve your requirement : search in the list yourself such as :

```
boolean hasNoEmptyElts =  myList.stream().noneMatch(s-> "".equals(s));
```

Or to filter out also `null` elements (as I assume in your context that you will not also consider them):

```
boolean hasNoEmptyElts =  myList.stream().noneMatch(s-> s == null || "".equals(s));
```

Or create a List wrapper that overrides `isEmpty()`.   This last way will do your code less standard (a custom List implementation instead of one of the JDK). So it would make sense only if this requirement is very frequent in your application.

Comment: This idea worked. Although the line had to be {myList.stream().noneMatch(s-> s == ""||s==null);}

Comment: @Ice Fine ! Note that you should compare String with `equals()` rather than `==` as two strings with the same content may not reference the same object.

Answer (score 2):

`data.trim()` will return an empty `String` for you (that is `""`).

So your list `a` contains a single empty `String`.

Therefore `a.isEmpty()` return false.

Answer (score 1):

All whitespaces are removed from the data string. A string is added to your ArrayList of strings, therefore a.isEmpty() returns false.

```
a.add(data.trim()); <---- A empty string is added to your ArrayList
```

Answer (score 0):

Do use *Apache* utils.

```
"   ".isEmpty();        // false
"".isEmpty();           // true
"   ".trim().isEmpty(); // true
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank("");       // true
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank("   ");    // true
```

It does not matter, empty `""` or blank `"   "` strings are placed into the list.

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("  ".trim()); // add empty string "" to the list: size == 1
```

To add not blank string to the list:

```
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(str))
    a.add(" foo ".trim()); // add "foo" string to the list
```

Comment: This answer misses the point. OP is calling `isEmpty()` on the `List`, not on the `String`.

Comment: My answer is for Title: `What happens when a string with only whitespaces is trimmed?`. Here is nothing about `list`